# boost to create guid in c++

Tags: c#, c++, boost

I am using `boost::uuids::uuid` to create guid from an array of characters but the result as I compare it with one using Guid in C# is fatally different.

C++

```
boost::uuids::uuid Guid(char data[16])
{

    return {
        data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], 
        data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], 
        data[8], data[9], data[10], data[11], 
        data[12], data[13], data[14], data[15] };
}
```

C#

```
Guid OnGuid(byte[] data)
{

    return new Guid(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, maybe show us what you get and what you expect?

Comment: The byte numbers from both are the same (expected), but the return value in one is garbage (C++) while the other is correct (xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx)  (C#). I need both to be the same in 2 languages.

Comment: Where does the data[] array come from, how do you initialize it?

Comment: I am serializing large binary objects transferred between protocols and I need to use their Guid (strings) to compare their identities.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data[] array that you are passing into these functions?

Comment: That means, the data arrays of both objects are their processed binary data embedded as blocks of bytes read into a structure as one of their attributes for serializing purpose. And during transfer I need to read them all out to match with the pre-calculated Guid data and let them pass through if their identities match with the original ones.

Comment: You ongoing questions make me feel sadder. This always seem endless. The data isn't hideous at all. It just badly sux.

Comment: @user1425671: We don't have enough information to diagnose the problem. Right now you show one function that initializes and returns a `uuid` and that's it.

Comment: "You ongoing questions make me feel sadder." - Imagine how we feel having to dredge some information out. This indeed always seems endless. But we're giving you a chance. Do you suggest we should just leave poorly posed questions, downvote and move on?